# How to fill multiple results from filter formula into each row of a table?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using the filter formula which return multiple results in a cell in excel table will always shows #SPILL! error. Is it possible to make each result fill in next row of the table? How should it be done? Thank you.

Comment: To my understanding you cannot use spilled array formulas within a table. It's also mentioned in documentation [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/dynamic-arrays-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531)

Comment: Then you may need combination of other formulas rather than filter formula. Show some sample data and output.